Python is throwing an error that GnuPG is not installed
I am getting the following error message:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbrowning\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mbrowning\Desktop\DDC Upload Training\DDC_Upload_File_Conversion.py", line 63, in convert_and_encrypt
    encrypt_file(output_txt, output_gpg, public_key_file)
  File "C:\Users\mbrowning\Desktop\DDC Upload Training\DDC_Upload_File_Conversion.py", line 25, in encrypt_file
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mbrowning\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\gnupg\gnupg.py", line 117, in __init__
    super(GPG, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Users\mbrowning\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\gnupg\_meta.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.binary  = _util._find_binary(binary)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mbrowning\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\gnupg\_util.py", line 429, in _find_binary
    raise RuntimeError("GnuPG is not installed!")
RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed!

I have installed, uninstalled, and reinstalled GnuPG and python-gnupg. I ahave also made sure it has been added to the system path.
My code should be producing an encrypted text file.

Could you, please, provide a minimal, reproducible example, i.e. list of installed Python packages, a Python input file and the command you are executing?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
